# How to check if a value is negative in a pandas MultiIndex and change it?

Tags: python, pandas

I have panda MultiIndex Series like

```
MultiIndex([('WELT', 'N24 DOKU'),
            ('WELT',     'WELT')],
           names=['mandant', 'brand'])
```

if I print it, I got

```
mandant  brand
WELT     N24 DOKU    -2064766.36
         WELT       -34179650.21
```

Now the question is, how can I check if is there a negative value and if so, set it to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC for get all negative values use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = s[s.lt(0)]
```

If need absolute values use [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html):

```
out = s.abs()
```

If need replace negative to to `0` use [`Series.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
out = s.clip(lower=0)

print (out)
mandant  brand   
WELT     N24 DOKU    0.0
         N24 DOKU    0.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Or some another value use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
out = s.mask(s.lt(0), 1)
print (out)
mandant  brand   
WELT     N24 DOKU    1.0
         N24 DOKU    1.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

put array indexes according to your code

```
df.index.get_level_values(0).drop_duplicates()[-2:]
```